# Position jQuery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried a million solutions and none seem to work. I just need to push my jQuery dialog box about 50px from the top of the page. Any ideas how?

```
function message() {
    $("#message").dialog({
      title: 'Title here',
      draggable:false,
      minHeight:100,
      resizable: false  
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) parameter for that, it accepts an array with X and Y coordinates :

```
function message() {
    var myPos = [ $(window).width() / 2, 50 ];

    $("#message").dialog({
      title: 'Title here',
      draggable:false,
      minHeight:100,
      position: myPos,
      resizable: false  
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbtB2/)

Comment: It's still a little off centered.. anyway to get it DEAD ON?

Comment: I think I might have gotten it.

Comment: and open event `open : function( event, ui ){   $(event.target).closest('.ui-dialog').css('top','50px'); }`

Answer (score 5):

Like adeneo [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15716354/137188), dialog has a `position` option which accepts a few data types, including jQuery-UI's fancy [position object](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/).

Given all the options, I think the cleanest and clearest way to specify the position you want is like this:

```
var myPos = { my: "center top", at: "center top+50", of: window };
```

Try it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbtB2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? css code `.myPosition`

```
.myPosition {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
```

and jquery

```
$('.selector').dialog({ dialogClass: 'myPosition' });
```