# jQuery Alert Box Fixed Location Issue?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a small issue getting my `jQuery` alert box to be positioned anywhere other than the **center** of the page. As soon as my button function is started and it opens its set to the **center** of the page.

I'm trying to use a class on the `div` to give it a fixed position to try and change this but still no joy does anyone know where I might be going wrong here?

Thanks.

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
}

$(function() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "puff",
      duration: 300
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "clip",
      duration: 500
    }
  });

  $("#opener").on("click", function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
  });

});
```

```css
.alertBox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="dialog1" class="alertBox" title="Alert Title!">
  <p>Alert Message Example</p>
</div>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">OPEN ALERT</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position jQuery dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716317/position-jquery-dialog-box)

Comment: Maybe you know this, but the #dialog1 div is outside of the body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Dialog has a built in [**position option**](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) that you could make use of:

> Specifies where the dialog should be displayed when opened. The dialog will handle collisions such that as much of the dialog is visible as possible.

```
$("#dialog1").dialog({
    position: {my: 'right bottom', at: 'right bottom'}
});
```

---

**Implemented into your code, it looks something like this:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
}

$(function() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "puff",
      duration: 300
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "clip",
      duration: 500
    },
    position: {my: 'right bottom', at: 'right bottom'}

  });

  $("#opener").on("click", function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
  });

});
```

```css
.alertBox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="dialog1" class="alertBox" title="Alert Title!">
  <p>Alert Message Example</p>
</div>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">OPEN ALERT</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog has a position property. You can set phrases like "`left`", "`center`", "`right`" and even combine it with `pixel/percentage` values.

`my` defines the elements position itself and `at` defines the position of the alignment to the target element.

**Have a look at this fiddle:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
}

$(function() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: {my: 'center+20px', at: 'bottom'},
    show: {
      effect: "puff",
      duration: 300
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "clip",
      duration: 500
    }
  });

  $("#opener").on("click", function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
  });

});
```

```css
.alertBox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="dialog1" class="alertBox" title="Alert Title!">
  <p>Alert Message Example</p>
</div>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">OPEN ALERT</button>
</body>

</html>
```